# Streaming player doesn't start video until its completely downloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to create a streaming link for the videos to run from mobile player, web browser or desktop streaming players (say VLC) alike. I am writing the code as below but video only starts playing when the file is completely downloaded instead of start playing as soon as sufficient chunk is downloaded and get the rest of the video alongside (like the normal behavior of any video streaming site).

```
def stream_video
  video_id = params[:id]
  video = Video.find(video_id)
  video_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/videos/"+video.path
  send_file(video_path,:file_name => video.path,:length => File.size(video_path),:disposition => 'inline', :stream => true,:x_sendfile => true)
end
```

Comment: What kind of video file?

Comment: John its mp4 file. i am not sure but i am trying this tutorial rightnow. [link] http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming

Comment: That tutorial is more for letting the browser start to parsing the HTML rather than streaming video.